# List Method in combination with initializing a new object

Tags: java, list

in my course i am actually at Lists and how to work with them. There is one command i dont fully get. I think the topic lists is pretty roff so please go easy on me.

Person node = list.remove(0);

Person is the Class
node the new Oject

What is inside of node now is what were inside of list.(index 0), why is that, didn't i remove what is inside of the list ?
Can i handle it the same way like:

Person node = list.get(0);
list.remove(0);

Comment: A List is a collection of objects, when you remove one from the list, the object still exists. Let's say that you have a collection of shoes and you give a pair to a friend. Those shoes aren't in your collection any more, you can't find them in your closet but your friend can use them. Keeping a reference to node, you can change its attributes and put it in another list or whatever. Also, it's not mandatory to assign the result of remove, if you're not going to use it, you can just remove it and forget about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Person node = list.get(0); 
list.remove(0);
```

is equivalent to:

```
Person node = list.remove(0);
```

It is how the method is defined in the `List` interface. When you remove, the method also returns the Object removed. More in docs here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-int-